# SQL Report Builder Table Dynamic Color

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, report

This might be beyond the limits of report builder.

I have an SQL Report that generates a table. The table is a fixed number of columns with a dynamic number of rows. The point of the table is to show recipe information of a system and I would like to make it more clear to a user when recipe information has been changed.

Example

```
+-----------+-------+-----+
| row names | Col A | Col |
+-----------+-------+-----+
| row1      |    10 |  20 |
| row2      |    14 |  20 |
+-----------+-------+-----+
```

The value of colA has changed so I would like to either change the cell color of row2,colA or change the font. To make it clear to a user what has changed.

I would want to do this dynamically for ever row. Basically compare to the row before and determine if I need to change colors of any of the cells.

Comment: when you say "compare the row before", do you mean the previous row in the report or the previous state of a row that you are not showing in the sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just mean you want to compare the previous row shown in the report then you can this is easily.

To recreate the exmaple, I used the following query in a dataset called `DataSet1`.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(RowID int, ColA int, ColB int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1,10,20),
(2,14,20),
(3,14,20),
(4,15,21),
(5,15,22)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I then created a simple table with the results sorted by RowID.

I then changed the `BackgroundColor` property of the cell containing `[ColA]` to the following expression.

```
=IIF(
    Fields!ColA.Value = Previous(Fields!ColA.Value) 
        OR Fields!RowID.Value = MIN(Fields!RowID.Value, "DataSet1")
    , Nothing
    , "Khaki"
    )
```

I repeated this for `Col B` changing the field name as applicable.
The expression simply checks if the value is the same as the previous row. For the first row with will always be false so I put a check in to see if we are formatting the first row. So if either (a) we are on the first row or (b) the number is the same as the previous number in this column, then the background is set to `Nothing` (the default), if neither of the conditions are met we set the background to 'Khaki'.

The end result looks like this...

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for! I knew that the background color could use an expression but I thought it would be for a static case switch situation. 

Is it possible to make this a property for all columns (based on its name) when making the table? I have 500 columns to do this for.

Answer (score 1):

The another way would be modifying the .RDL file.The RDL file basically contains XML tags so if you open them in Notepad or Visual Studio using View Code .You will find a tag called **BackgroundColor** for each and every column .By giving the color code in the place of existing one will get you the desired color.you can design a custom color and use it in your report.